# Get smtpaddress from outlook using mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty

Tags: c#, outlook, smtp, getproperty

I have been trying to find sources for the following, i have to rework a piece of code which is not working. It runs on our clients machine, they are very security aware and block almost everything. Can a group policy block the following fro doing a call to the location http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C190102?

The code below is where the problem is, it doesn't throw and error or break the app it just doesn't do anything, can anyone see if i am doing anything wrong calling it as it is? I am new to working with outlook integration so not sure if i should paste more code for readability, if so please let me know.

I am kind at a loss here as they are running an exchange, and we dont have one so i cant test it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

var senderEntryId = mailItem.PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString(mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(senderSmtpAddress));

Comment: What is the value of the senderSmtpAddress property? It looks like your code assumes that it is retrieving a sender entry id. What is it?

Comment: Hi, the value assigned is the following: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C190102", I am unsure if the value changes with newer versions of Outlook, as I am using the on Outlook 2016, the add-in was written for Outlook 2007, and now modified some of the code to work for 2016. The used commandbars before, i modified it to use vsto add-ins now.